# MariaDB - Как хранить много информации в одном ряду(пользователя)?

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, telegram, mariadb

У меня есть таблица, в ней несколько столбцов, ранее чтобы сохранять много информации о пользователе(в моем случае нужно хранить данные с каждой ГРУППЫ телеграм) я использовал json, но потом понял что на обновление и добавление новых ключей каждому пользователю это слижком сложно и долго. Как можно сохранять много информации с каждой группы но не в JSON?

Comment: сделайте таблицу: id, id_пользователя, ключ, значение и храните все дополнительные данные в ней

Comment: Ну единственный паттерн хранения неопределённого числа атрибутов, кроме сериализованных форматов - это EAV.

Comment: Akina спасибо, это идея!